# Unwanted page break between a section heading and its subsection heading

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, pdfpages

My scenario consists of some sections and subsections. A slice of the aforementioned group has been presented, as below:

```
\tableofcontents    

\clearpage

\section{parent}

%\subsection{child}
\includepdf[trim=0 0 0 -7cm,pages=1,pagecommand=\subsection{child}]{"D:/A/A_"}
\includepdf[trim=0 0 0 -3cm, pages=2-,pagecommand={}]{"D:/A/A_"}
```

Each section acts just as an empty parent container for its child subsection. So, one might infer that the subsection must be placed right after its corresponding section heading. But the result after compilation would be:

```
\section{parent}
% page break does occur here
\subsection{child}
```

I have not modified the default `section` nor `subsection`, nor any other command in this file.

- I have just tried a solution using the `samepage` environment, but that did lead to nothing promising.
- Using `\nobreak` & `\nopagebreak` commands did not help, too.
- Plus useless utilization of [`\let\clearpage\relax`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209065/to-have-no-pagebreak-after-include-in-latex).

Would you please help me to handle this case?

Comment: if you use `pagecommand=\subsection{child}` the subsection heading will be in the included page so new page after `\section`.

Comment: @touhami: So, what kind of modification should I apply to resolve that new page?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created the following 10-page [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\sloppy
\vspace*{5cm}
\begin{center}
  \bfseries This is \verb|lipsum[1-50]|
\end{center}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

This is how I would include it in the way you may be after (which avoids a page-break:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\section{Parent}

%\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\subsection{Child}}]{lipsum50}
\subsection{Child}
\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[\textwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[page=1,trim=0 0 0 9cm,clip]{lipsum50}%
}}

\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{lipsum50}
\end{document}
```

The main approach is to include the first page using `\includegraphics[page=1,...]{<file>}` from [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) (loaded by [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)).

Some adjustments need to made to ensure proper loading:

- We `trim` (and `clip`) the first page so only the relevant content is included. Based on your example, it seems like you have some blank space at the top of the first page.
- The included first page is "raised" into position with a `0pt` height *and* depth so it doesn't affect any overflow (vertically).
- Subsequent pages are included in the usual way using `\includepdf`, with an accompanying `\thispagestyle` that matches the rest of your document.

Note that the above relies on the fact that your text block is centred on the page. Additional adjustments are required if this is not the case.

Comment: Amazing solution... You precisely hit the mark... Thanks in advance